# Attaching eventListener to dynamic elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener, event-delegation

I'm making a todo list and I have li and button tags added dynamically when adding a new list item. The button is an x which is supposed to remove the list item. I have tried several things but can't figure out how to make an `eventListener` for each individual x button and remove the corresponding list item when it is clicked.

The `renderTodos` function is where all of the dynamically added content is created. I have a data-index set to each button in which I was trying to use to access each button to attach an `eventListener` on each dynamic button, but I wasn't sure how to implement that. From what I have read there should be a way to do this using the `currentTarget` or target of the event but I don't understand how that works.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[name=todoItem]'),

btnAdd = document.querySelector('button[name=add]'),
btnClear = document.querySelector('button[name=clear]'),
list = document.querySelector('.todo'),
storeList = [];

function renderTodos(){
  var el = document.createElement('li'),
  x = document.createElement('button');
  listLength = storeList.length;
  
  //Set text for remove button
  x.innerHTML = 'x';

  for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
    el.innerHTML = storeList[i];
    list.appendChild(el);
    x.setAttribute('data-index', i);
    el.appendChild(x);
  }

  // check for correct data-index property on x button
}

function addTodos(){
  storeList.push(input.value);

  // Check that input is getting pushed to list array
  console.log(storeList);
  renderTodos();
}


function clearList(){
  // make list empty
  list.innerHTML = '';
  storeList.splice(0, storeList.length);
  //render empty list
  renderTodos();
  
  //Check that list array is empty
  console.log(storeList);
}

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', addTodos);
btnClear.addEventListener('click', clearList);
```

Everything else on the list works so far I just can't figure out how to implement this `eventListener`.

Comment: renderTodos is just adding the list items and the x button whenever the add button is clicked, which is what it's supposed to be doing. I just need to figure out how to click the added x button in order to remove the associated list item.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. When I look at the dev tools and add multiple items to the list it shows a list item and button being created everytime I click the add button. And everytime I click the clear button it removes all of the li and buttons. What do you mean there are no new elements being created? Sorry if I'm missing something simple I just don't really understand.

Comment: I missed `list.appendChild(el);`. What it's doing is cycling through all the members of *storeList* each time, the only one you see is the last one. You don't need a for loop, nor do you need to "render the empty list". A for loop over an array with length zero does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to each button using something like:

```
 x.innerHTML = '';
 x.onclick = function(){
   var node = this.parentNode;
   node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
 };
```

Or you can keep the *renderTodos* code as it is and delegate the remove to the parent UL:

```
// Add the listener
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

// The listener function
function removeItem(event) {
  var node = event.target;

  // Check that the click came from an X button
  // better to check against a class name though
  if (node.tagName &&
      node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button' &&
      node.innerHTML == 'x') {
    node = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you this was very helpful. I'll probably change a few things such as the class you mentioned for button and try some things out, but this works as it is.

Answer (score 1):

One simple example can be

```js
//a click hadler is added to #mylist which is already present in the dom
document.querySelector('#mylist').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //assuming that the the `x` is in a span and it is the only span in the `li` we check for that, we can improve this check more to make sure we have actually clicked on the delete button
  if (e.target.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    //if so then since we know the structure we can delete the parent node of the target which is the span element
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
  }
}, false);

//kindly forgive the use of jQuery here
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('<li />', {
    text: i
  }).append('<span class="x">X</span>').appendTo('#mylist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist"></ul>
```

This is a very basic implementation of event delegation, where the actual event is bound to an ancestor element but then we use the actual event target to determine whether to act on it. We can improve the `if` condition to test for an class for any other attribute!!!

Comment: Thank you this is the kind of help I was looking for! Just something to give me an example of something similar, not a line for line solve my own problem for me. This is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

basically what you want to do is add an event on the parent container and wait for the event to bubble up and identify if the event originating is from your x mark and if it is then trigger the callback function.. This is the concept I think most of the libraries use..

Or use a library like jQuery, why solve a problem that has already been solved by others.

Comment: Everything on this site comes down to use jquery. Why use jquery on something this small? Add a whole library just for a few relatively simple things like this seems unnecessary. And the main point of this project is that I'm trying to learn and understand events in javascripts itself. I'll never understand what jquery is really doing if I can't do it in plain javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the parent container explanation that does help a little. I kind of had an idea I needed to do that I am just not sure how to do it.

Comment: do you understand what OR is!!!! why dont you implement it! I dont see an attempt by you.. do you want us to spoon feed every prob that u run into?

Comment: there are so many intricacies involved that it is difficult to get it right (for all browsers, controls) and that is why people use/recommend tried and tested solutions and not rollout homegrown solution every time. looks like people are busy trying to save 28kb of data but dont mind having javascript code like document.addEventListener and etc

Comment: Yes I know what or is.  You don't have to help, sorry if you feel so obliged to answer every question on here in order to get higher reputation and feel good about yourself as a programmer. I'm new to this and don't understand a lot of things yet. I thought that's what this site was made for. And I have, as stated in the problem, attempted to implement this in various ways, but nothing I had was even close or looked right so why post it if it's just going to make it harder to read and see what the problem is. I don't want the answer spelled out line for line, just an idea of how to use target.

Comment: i dont care abt the reputation.. if i did i wouldnt have bothered replying.. im back on this site like after 2 years!

Comment: @Baz1nga—even using a library, the code for the remove listener still has to be written, as does the code to attach it, which ends up being about the same amount of code. There is more to be saved by the OP learning how to do this efficiently than "use jQuery". Some of the most verbose and inefficient code I've seen has used one library or another.